Why do I get the error message "Error: Could not find or load main class Main Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main" on IntelliJ?
I am trying to a simple HelloWorld program automatically generated by IntelliJ through IntelliJ that is running on a Linux Mint installation. I can run the code through the terminal if I navigate directly to the .java file, but not when I run through IntelliJ (Using Shift+F10 or any other method). When I try to run, it generates this command and then fails:
/home/username/.jdks/openjdk-22.0.2/bin/java -javaagent:/home/username/Programs/Binaries and Scripts/IntelliJ/idea-IC-242.20224.387/lib/idea_rt.jar=42113:/home/username/Programs/Binaries and Scripts/IntelliJ/idea-IC-242.20224.387/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/username/Network Drive/School and Education/School/MOOC/Data Structures and Algorithms I: Arrays/JUnit/JUnit Testing Practice/JUnit Test Project/out/production/JUnit Test Project Main
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
Process finished with exit code 0
I've tried all solutions given in this answer:
Error: Could not find or load main class in intelliJ IDE
as well as installing the Flatpak version to see if it was some kind of configuration issue from the installer from the JetBrains website, but nothing seemed to make any difference whatsoever.

I resolved this issue after several hours by testing out different places of saving the project, because I thought it might have something to do with the file being on a network drive.
The problem ended up being the filepath. Specifically, the fact that the filepath had the ":" character in it. In my case it was this bolded folder here:
/home/username/.jdks/openjdk-22.0.2/bin/java -javaagent:/home/username/Programs/Binaries and Scripts/IntelliJ/idea-IC-242.20224.387/lib/idea_rt.jar=42113:/home/username/Programs/Binaries and Scripts/IntelliJ/idea-IC-242.20224.387/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/username/Network Drive/School and Education/School/MOOC/Data Structures and Algorithms I: Arrays/JUnit/JUnit Testing Practice/JUnit Test Project/out/production/JUnit Test Project Main
I had copied the name for this folder, and didn't realize there was a colon in there. After removing the colon from the filepath for the project location, everything worked as expected.
